# trouble with resampling objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've got a class that has two attributes: a value `val` and a weight `weight`. Then I have a list of these.

As step 1 of 2, I want to sample with replacement from this list of objects. Since it's sampling with replacement, the result list will usually have duplicate objects (objects with matching values and weights).

As step 2 of 2, I want to jitter each of these objects' values. Each of these objects has an `update()` method. It adds some noise to its value object. I do not want objects with matching values to have matching values after `update()` has been called.

How can get the desired behavior? What is the fastest way to do it? I've played around with `copy.deepcopy` but I can't get anything to change the behavior. Below is a small example.

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val, weight):
        self.val = val
        self.weight = weight
    def update(self):
        self.val += np.random.normal()        

np.random.seed(1)        
orig = [MyClass(np.random.normal(), np.abs(np.random.normal())) for _ in range(10)]
wt = [elem.weight for elem in orig]
wt /= np.sum(wt)
shuffled = np.random.choice(a=orig, size=len(orig), replace=True, p=wt)
for o in shuffled:
    o.update()
[o.val for o in shuffled]
print(shuffled[0].val == shuffled[2].val) # not ok
```

### Edit:

This works. But is there a quicker way? Why am I required to re-instantiate?

```
np.random.seed(1)        
orig = [MyClass(np.random.normal(), np.abs(np.random.normal())) for _ in range(10)]
wt = [elem.weight for elem in orig]
wt /= np.sum(wt)
idx = np.random.choice(len(orig), size=len(orig), replace=True, p=wt)
vs = [orig[i].val for i in idx]
ws = [orig[i].weight for i in idx]
shuffled = [MyClass(v,w) for v,w in zip(vs,ws)]
for o in shuffled:
    o.update()
[o.val for o in shuffled]
```

Comment: a and resampled are not defined.

Comment: @ayhan sorry. fixed.

Comment: What do you mean "change the behavior"?  If you want to make copies and it's not working, you should probably show the code that uses `deepcopy` and explain what it isn't doing that you want it to do.

Comment: I've changed the title. I'm not sure that it's an issue that involves `copy.deepcopy`. You can't really deepcopy a constituent float. I would just like to unlink the result of `update` between objects that started off with the same value `val`

Comment: It might be easier to just store the parameters in `orig` and then create the MyClass instances *after* sampling.  That way you would generate a separate MyClass instance per sample.

Comment: @BrenBarn yeah it is easier. But in my real program I resample repeatedly. I'd be delaying the inevitable

Comment: @Taylor: Every time you want to create independent objects, you're going to need to create new instances of `MyClass`.  If you resample a bunch of times and need to create new independent values, you're going to need to create even more new instances of `MyClass`.  Since you have to create those instances anyway, you might as well create them as part of the sampling rather than by deepcopying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117985/discussion-between-taylor-and-brenbarn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need that `class MyClass`? I think object oriented code should be used where you have a collection of heterogeneous data and accompanying methods, and/or use inheritance. Since you're just working with NxM floats, simply using `numpy.array`s here is far easier to understand, maintain and use, IMHO:

```
import numpy as np

def update(x):
    x += np.random.normal(size=x.size)

def equal_elem(x):
    x.sort()
    v = np.searchsorted(x, x)
    return np.any(v - np.arange(v.size))

size = 10

vals = np.random.normal(size=size)
weights = np.abs(np.random.normal(size=size))
weights /= weights.sum()

svals = np.random.choice(vals, size=vals.size, replace=True, p=weights)
update(svals)
while equal_elem(svals):
    update(svals)
```

The `equal_elem` check might jitter all elements in `svals` again, using the current values in `svals`. If you want to avoid that, you could create another variable `retvals`, and change the `update` function to return an array instead of modifying it in-place.